# Are there plans to make all members of class Breeze.WebApi.EntityInfo public?

Tags: breeze

I need to subclass Breeze.WebApi.ContextProvider, but it uses EntityInfo which has internal contructor :(
Are there plans to make all members of class EntityInfo public?

```
  public class EntityInfo {
    internal EntityInfo() {
    }

    public Object Entity { get; internal set; }
    public EntityState EntityState { get; internal set; }
    public Dictionary<String, Object> OriginalValuesMap { get; internal set; }
    internal AutoGeneratedKey AutoGeneratedKey;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have discussed making them protected, so that a subclass can set them internally. (see EFEntityInfo for example), but we didn't have a good use case for making them public.

Would "protected" be sufficient for your use case? or do you really need "public"?

Comment: I think protected makes more sense here. I'd be concerned with making the core classes public.

Comment: Protected would be ok - no need to make them public indeed.